# Internal Tester radio button not showing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, app-store-connect

I added a new user to iTunes connect to become one of the 25 internal testers available for prerelease testing on that started with iOS 8. When I go to this user's profile on "Users and Roles" > "[Name of user]" I'm not seeing this button at all:

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the role of the new user. Under the "Roles" tab:

[image]

You must allow the new user to at least have "technical" access. As shown:

[image]

Even though it says "In-App Purchase Tester" this also correlates with being an "Internal Tester" (1 of 25 max) through the new TestFlight protocol as recently integrated with iTunesConnect.

Note that the the device must be running iOS 8 and must have the new TestFlight app from the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the internal tester switch check that you are signed in to iTunes Connect with an Admin or Legal account (NOT a Technical account). This answer explains further https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046745/3055537