# I can't add testers to iTunes Connect: Users and Roles → TestFlight Beta Testers → Internal

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm a developer for a small company's team. I am trying to set up Apple's TestFlight service.

I have a Beta submitted for a new release. I have turned on TestFlight testing for this build. However, when I try to invite testers, I am told that I need to enable some users for this role.

When I go to the "Users and Roles – TestFlight Beta Testers – Internal" section of iTunes connect, I see the list of other people in the company's team. There is a check mark to the left of each person to select them. iTunes Connect won't allow me to select any of the users and doesn't give an error.

How can I add testers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my case, this happened because I was set up with the `Technical` role in the iTunes Connect team.

**Users with the `Technical` role are *not* authorised to add internal beta testers.**

You need to find someone within the team who has either the **`Admin` or `Legal`** role in iTunes connect.

This person can then either:

- Set up testers themself.
- Set you up to have the `Admin` role, at which point, you will be able to add testers yourself.

Without the `Admin` or `Legal` role, you will not be able to set up testers.

The UI does not seem to have any feedback to inform you of this, which is unfortunate.

Comment: yes they should at least give some sort of indication that you are not authorised for this action.

Comment: I also had this issue. Mine was caused by adding an email as an external tester and an internal tester. If a user is an external tester for an app, they can't be an internal tester as well. Sounds obvious, but when your first learning how this all works it can be confusing.

Comment: I have a user setup as Admin and when I try to add someone it just keeps saying the have an existing apple id and it won't work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @mikeLspohn It means that the address you are using is already associated with an iTunes Connect team. You'll need to use a different email address.

Comment: This is what I found from iTunes Connect Developer Guide: "All iTunes Connect users (except users with only a Marketing role) can view the settings for all other iTunes Connect users in their organization. However, users with an Admin role are the only ones who can delete or modify user accounts, including setting roles and notifications." [Setting Up User Accounts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)

Answer (score 16):

Apple makes this process painfully un-obvious, but here are some steps that may help:

- Login to iTunes Connect and navigate to "Users & Roles > iTunes Connect Users"
- Click the + icon near the top to add a new user
- ADD THEM TO THE "TECHNICAL" ROLE!!  This is the important part Apple fails to explain.  If a user isn't assigned to the "Technical" role, their name won't appear in the list of users to select from under the "Users & Roles > TestFlight Beta Testers" section.
- The new user will receive an email invite.  Prior to them accepting, you will not see their name under your list of users.  Once they accept, their name will be listed.
- Navigate to "Users & Roles > TestFlight Beta Testers" check the box next to their name and click Save. 
  -OR- 
  Navigate back "Users & Roles > iTunes Connect Users" click on the new user's name and in the upper right corner, switch the "Internal Tester" toggle to ON.
- Navigate to "My Apps > (app name) > Pre-release > Internal Testers" check the box next to the new user's name and click "Invite"

NOTE: I could be wrong about this next part but in my experience, the new user will not receive an invite for a previous build.  You must publish a new build *after* the new user is added.  Only then will they receive the invite.

Comment: Now I don't see Technical option at all!

Comment: No Technical option. What now?

Comment: It's a "developer" role now. You have to now trust 'em more I suppose

Comment: In my case, "developer" doesn't work, but roles like marketing and sales do work.... weird!

Comment: why is it developer now? A tester is clearly not the same thing as a developer. You may not want another developer on your app. Why is there no tester role?

Answer (score 10):

As of late 2015 / early 2016 Apple has started to decommission the *Technical* role and replace it with the *App Manager* role. A new role of *Developer* was created, which also allows internal testing through TestFlight, while having somewhat less privileges.
Unfortunately the hint text on the TestFlight panel is still not updated and lists only the defunct *Technical* role besides *Admin* and *Legal*, causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: Apple stahp please.

Answer (score 1):

#### 2023 update:

On the add users section in testflight in appstoreconnect you can see the permissions of each role listed when you click "See permissions":

[image]

From there you might be able to figure out which role suits your need best for your tester