# iTunes Connect - Can't invite "internal testers" for prerelease app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I got my app approved for distribution through the new Apple TestFlight app. I tried to invite an "internal tester" through `iTunes Connect ->Prerelease ->Internal Testers` but all I see are 2 info boxes:

> 1. *To start testing, select at least one Internal Tester.*
> 2. *Internal testers can be added in Users and Roles. Internal testers are iTunes Connect users with the Admin or Technical role.*

I already added an Admin an Technical user to `Users and Roles` but I can't invite them.
How to invite an internal tester?

Comment: dont forget to approve right answer for improving SO.

Comment: Just a note, that this question and all of it's answers are now outdated with the new version of iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 60):

Problem solved: The email for an internal tester was also used for an external tester. As soon as I removed the email from the external testers list I could invite the user as an internal tester.

Comment: Tanks! Helped me a lot!

Comment: Another proof of the wonderful developer-friendly UX of apple

Comment: Lol everyone is doing the same mistake :)

Comment: Didn't work. Still have the same message "You can't add any additional internal testers."

Answer (score 10):

To add people to internal testers you need to go

1. "Users and Roles"
2. List item
3. Select the user Switch on Internal Tester
4. Save

[image]

Comment: I did that but the user is not showing under the internal testers for my app. Can a user only be invited to 1 app?

Comment: I can't get the 'invite' button to appear, no matter what I do.  I've tried everything suggested here.

Comment: I cannot see Internal Tester switch in User list. where is it?

Comment: @David are you signed in to iTunes Connect with an Admin or Legal account? if not the button won't appear :( - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27046745/3055537

Comment: Yeah, I would have all privies. That makes sense if you don't have the proper account you won't see this.

Answer (score 6):

1. users and roles - external tester - remove email
2. users and roles - interal tester - click checkbox and save
3. my app - appname - prerelease - iternal testers - click checkbox and click invite.

it save me from going crazy)

Comment: Thank you I had that exact same situation. Not at all obvious that that was the issue.

Comment: @BenKane yeah, sometimes apple make not obvious desigions.

Comment: Realise this was a while ago, but if you were here right now - I'd for real kiss you

Comment: @mcabe =* heh, ikr

Answer (score 1):

Something else that might help is if you flick the "Internal Tester" switch on a user and it doesn't stay, you have to make sure, as Apple says [in this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html) "The user must have an Admin, Legal, or Technical role."

Answer (score 0):

To add a beta tester you must be signed in to iTunes Connect with an Admin or Legal account (NOT a Technical account). This answer explains further https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046745/3055537

Comment: my first down vote - I'm kinda new here so I'm still trying to learn the culture. If you could explain why then i can try and not make the same mistake again. I thought the answer was relevant because I had the same problem (unable to add an internal tester), and the others answers didn't solve my problem.

Comment: what could be done if the legal/admin account is given a Technical role in itunesconnect, is there anyway to revert that ?