# Cannot add an internal beta tester to Apple's TestFlight - what am I missing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have enabled my app for TestFlight testing and invited a bunch of beta testers and successfully added them to my project. However I cannot add a single *internal* tester. The UI just shows me that I should select at least one user, however there are no users to select from.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- I am Admin in the Users & Roles
- I invited two internal testers.
- Both have confirmed the invitation and agreed.
- Both testers have the *Technical* role.
- For both testers *TestFlight testing* is enabled.
- Beta Tests are enabled on the uploaded build

This is what the UI looks for me:
[image]

Comment: Did you activated "Betatests mit TestFlight" for your Build Version?

Comment: @LoVo Where would that be?

Comment: When you upload a new app version, click on Builds (on the left from your Internal Tester on your screenshot) and activate the slider on the right side for your build which says: "Betatests mit TestFlight "

Comment: That is already enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes Connect - Can't invite "internal testers" for prerelease app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908545/itunes-connect-cant-invite-internal-testers-for-prerelease-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. The users are already added as *external beta* testers. Removing them from there, makes them show up on the *internal* tab. Not too obvious IMHO.